# What's the difference between System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: html, vb.net, urlencode

They both encode html

Why microsoft use several different function?

Which one is better?

are there any strings that are encoded differently between 2 functions?

I notice that System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode doesn't work in client framework. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters you're comparing apples to oranges.  `HtmlEncode` deals with characters specific to the HTML language, where `UrlEncode` is for formatting characters that aren't valid in a URL.

They both have their uses, and by their names it should be obvious which you need to use for the problem you're trying to solve.

The Client Framework excludes those .Net features that are typically only used in server applications...of course we usually find that we need that one method which isn't included in the Client Framework to do what we need, so alot of projects that do something creative or interesting end up targeting the full .Net Framework by the time they are finished.

Comment: are there any strings that are encoded differently between 2 functions?

Comment: I believe UrlEncode will convert a space to +, while HtmlEncode does nothing.